# Emulating an hardware printer

Tags: printer, serial, emulation

I have an old machinery that does some analysis and print out the results on an Epson LX300, connected via a serial port 25 pin.

Is possible to connect this machinery to a computer in order to digitalize the analysis results directly, emulating the printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible if the computer has a 25-pin serial port. I once did a database migration by printing the entire database to a computer over a serial link, capturing the output to disk, and then parsing the data into the new database. I believe that USB to 25-pin-serial adaptors are available.

Comment: Do I need any supplementary hardware between the machinery and the pc/usb adapter like a null modem adapter?

Comment: @Nicola It's decades since I did much fiddling with serial connections, but you might need a null modem -- it depends how the serial ports on the printer and PC are wired.